# How to get the text of all the elements in a given html in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How to extract all the text of elements from the following html:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html3 = """
<div class="tab-cell l1">
    <span class="cyan-90">***</span>
    <h2 class="white-80">
        <a class="k-link" href="#" title="Jump">Jump</a>
    </h2>
    <h3 class="black-70">
        <span>Red</span>
        <span class="black-50">lock</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="l-block">
        <a class="lang-menu" href="#">A</a>
        <a class="lang-menu" href="#">B</a>
        <a class="lang-menu" href="#">C</a>
    </div>
    <div class="black-50">
        <div class="p-bold">Period</div>
        <div class="tab--cell">$</div><div class="white-90">Method</div>
        <div class="tab--cell">$</div><div class="tab--cell">Type</div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html3, "lxml")
if soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'tab-cell l1'}):
    div_descendants = soup.div.descendants
    for des in div_descendants:
       if des.name is not None:
           print(des.name)
           if des.find(class_='k-link'):
               print(des.a.string)
           if des.find(class_='black-70'):
               print('span')
               print(des.span.text)
```

I'm getting text of only first link, after that I'm unable to get anything.
I would like to crawl line by line and get whatever I want, if anyone have any idea please let me know.

Comment: So far you have unresolved reference to `div` on this line `div_descendants = div.descendants`.

Comment: my mistake, forgotten one line...

Comment: Well, the `div.descendants` is still unresolved. Moving it around won't resolve it. You have to declare it first.

Comment: resolved div.descendants

Comment: Initially, I tried to get the text by slicing des like des[2], des[4] where I failed So I find the other way around but after getting the first value in the same way I thought that I will get the remaining values too but that is not happening...

Answer (score 1):

Your own `if`-conditions hinder you to get all things. You only print in two cases based on a `class_=...` condition - you do not print in all conditions:

```
# html3 = see above 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html3, "lxml")
if soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'tab-cell l1'}):
    div_descendants = soup.div.descendants
    for des in div_descendants:
        if des.name is not None:
            print(des.name)
            found = False
            if des.find(class_='k-link'):
                print(des.a.string)
                found = True
            if des.find(class_='black-70'):
                print('span')
                print(des.span.text)
                found = True
            # find all others that are not already reported:
            if not found:
                print(f"Other {des.name}: {des.string}")
```

Output:

```
span
Other span: ***
h2
Jump
a
Other a: Jump
h3
Other h3: None
span
Other span: Red
span
Other span: lock
div
Other div: None
a
Other a: A
a
Other a: B
a
Other a: C
div
Other div: None 
div
Other div: Period
div
Other div: $
div
Other div: Method
div
Other div: $
div
Other div: Type
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out the issue like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml


html3 = """
<div class="tab-cell l1">
    <span class="cyan-90">***</span>
    <h2 class="white-80">
        <a class="k-link" href="#" title="Jump">Jump</a>
    </h2>
    <h3 class="black-70">
        <span>Red</span>
        <span class="black-50">lock</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="l-block">
        <a class="lang-menu" href="#">A</a>
        <a class="lang-menu" href="#">B</a>
        <a class="lang-menu" href="#">C</a>
    </div>
    <div class="black-50">
        <div class="p-bold">Period</div>
        <div class="tab--cell">$</div><div class="white-90">Method</div>
        <div class="tab--cell">$</div><div class="tab--cell">Type</div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html3, "lxml")
if soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'tab-cell l1'}):
    div_descendants = soup.div.descendants
    for des in div_descendants:
        if des.name is not None and des.string is not None:
            print(f"{des.name}: {des.string}")
```